# С помощью каких плагинов можно вывести новости в elementor?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

С помощью какого плагина возможно организовать вывод новостей в обычном elementor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать плагин Essential addons, Сетка записей.